# Event bubbling seems not working when using bootstrap modal in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

I got a some questions about using bootstrap modal.

First of all, sorry for my English skill, maybe there are some problems to understand my question.

I made a button as a `directive` to add dynamically with reference to below links.

.

[Angularjs dynamically adding and removing elements using directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429854/angularjs-dynamically-adding-and-removing-elements-using-directive)

http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/4ktmvzcm/1/

^^^^^ above link is just what I consulted.

.

And my problem is in this fiddle.

.

https://jsfiddle.net/CRDeity/6kmszgL0/

.

When I put this into a `modal`, even though I click this, it didn't work.

If outside of `modal`, this worked well.

Are there any interruption in `event` of `modal`?

Comment: In the fiddle, just add the modal code which is not working

Comment: @Thusitha Oh I'm really sorry. What I brought was wrong fiddle. Now I changed it.

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be a modal in your example;  This is a prime example of why you should include code *in the question body*.

Comment: @Claies Now I updated fiddle where has my problem. sorry to give confusing. What you've seen was what I consulted.

Comment: really appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you solution.

Check this fiddle.

[Directive have to use `snake-case`](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/dn9qxsLk/)

When using directive, you have to consider `snake-case` using `-`.

```
<button add-item-line class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
    Add list
</button>
```

Comment: Oh.. It was my silly mistake.. thanks a lot! I wanna give you +1 but I can't. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your directive is not declared correctly.  Angular uses Attribute Normalization to link Directives to Elements, because HTML is case insensitive, while JavaScript is case sensitive.  (see [Matching Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) for more info).  The Directive `'addItemLine'` and `'additemline'` would be exactly the same, without this normalization.

In the HTML, you use Dash Delimited names, which are converted to their Camel Case equivalent.  Therefore, to reach the `'addItemLine'` Directive, you need the `add-item-line` Attribute.

```
<button add-item-line class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
```

Working version of your example:  https://jsfiddle.net/bLanoznz/

Comment: Oh.. It was my silly mistake.. thanks a lot! I wanna give you `check`, but sorry for cannot use this more than once.. but thank you anyway. :)