# How to change the directive of an input text with angular 1.6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I have two directives in the **app.js**, which are for following onkeypress validation, one directive is to validate **only numerics** and the other directive validate **only letters [A-Z]**.

```
<input type="text" id="txt_siaf" class="form-control" ng-model="siaf" maxlength="10" valid-numeric />
```

Given that my input text currently assigns a **valid-numeric** directive, I need to know how to change it by the **valid-letters** directive.

I would appreciate your support.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't think so that you can add or remove directive dynamically from input but you can play with other work around like:

in controller:

```
$scope.validNumericDirective = true;
```

and in template:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_siaf" ng-if="validNumericDirective" class="form-control" ng-model="siaf" maxlength="10" valid-numeric />
<input type="text" id="txt_siaf" ng-if="!validNumericDirective" class="form-control" ng-model="siaf" maxlength="10" valid-letters />
```

this logic will do the trick but you have to toggle `validNumericDirective` in your controller on any event.

**Update:**
There is a way where you can add or remove directive dynamically but it has a lengthy process see:

[Angularjs dynamically adding and removing elements using directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429854/angularjs-dynamically-adding-and-removing-elements-using-directive)

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038684/AngularJs-Add-Remove-Directives-Dynamically-Save-D

Answer (score 2):

```
    **You change the value of variable $scope.showNumericDirective dynamically.**

Add in template
    <input type="text" ng-if="showNumericDirective" id="txt_siaf" class="form-control" ng-model="siaf"  valid-numeric />
    <input type="text" ng-if="!showNumericDirective" id="txt_siaf" class="form-control" ng-model="siaf" valid-letters />

    var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

    myapp.controller('controllerName', function($scope)
    {
    $scope.showNumericDirective = true;
    });
    myapp.directive('validNumeric', function() {

    });
    myapp.directive('validLetters', function() {

    });
```